# Updating the Django cache programmatically

Tags: django-cache

I plan to cache some of my endpoints powered by DRF, and I want to update the cache wherever it is appropriate. So basically I need to somehow understand what key corresponds to the given cache. As far as I understand, Django does not provide such an opprotunity, right ?
Before inventing a bicycle, I would like to make sure that there's no inbuilt feature for it.

For example, I have the following code:

from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response

class CachedAPIView(APIView):
@cache_page(60 * 15)  # Cache for 15 minutes
def get(self, request):
# Your view logic here
data = {'message': 'This is a cached response!'}
return Response(data)

```
def post(self, request):
    # Here I want to somehow locate my key based on query details and update its value
```